# How to disable fetching in bidirectional @OneToMany @ManyToOne relation. Spring DATA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading, parent-child

Please, help me to find a way to get Parent @Entity in bidirectional Parent - Child relation without it's child @Entities. Thank you!
Parent entity (w/o a few not important fields):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANIES")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Lazy
@Builder
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "increment")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ID", updatable = false) //updatable
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100, name = "NAME", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true) 
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUPONS", indexes = @Index(name = "TitleIndex", columnList = "COMPANY_ID, TITLE", unique = true))
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Lazy
@Builder
public class Coupon {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "increment")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ID", updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100, name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "coupon", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Purchase> purchase = new ArrayList<>();
```

I already tried using these annotations on parent entity with @OneToMany annotation:

- @JsonIgnoreProperties("coupons")
- @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
- @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

List of dependencies:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.jb</groupId>
<artifactId>coupons3web</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>coupons3web</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

JSON which i receive if I try to get one Company (parent entity) which has Coupons (child entities):

```
{"id":2,"name":"Facebook","email":"k3","password":"$2a$10$WHBxW62w07mNcT8UcaiPw.MmAB/TjbIjcTM2fcmIiCjri5ac59ba.","coupons":[{"id":1,"title":"Travel","description":"RK49NZi3L7","startDate":"2021-05-27","endDate":"2021-06-17","amount":3400,"price":163.55,"image":"qq3eUAJx0CnxnOtkv2HB","purchase":[{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":2}},{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":5}},{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":6}},{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":12}},{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":16}},{"id":{"couponID":1,"customerID":19}}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

- According to what i know, the answer is you can't. Hibernate mapping
  by entity so you always have the whole child object.
- I don't know what you want to do but i think you should just get the
  whole child list object then modify it (maybe by a stream.map()
  function) to become a list childId as you want
- Use can Native queries for only can getting Parent Instead of Hibernate in built methods because internally they fire queries according to your mapping(independent of lazy and eager loading)

-If You Want to know currently what are the queries fired internally u can use in apllication.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Hope this Answer Will Help You .

Comment: Thank you, IshanI thought fetchType=LAZY should help in this situation. It doesn't work because the relation is bidirectional with mappedBy atribute on the @OneToMany side?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is exactly that you want to disable, but I guess you are seeing an additional select for fetching the coupons? In that case, you should either use `EAGER` on the `@OneToMany` or use an entity graph to specify that the coupons collection should be join fetched.

Comment: Thank you Christian. At the end I avoided using @EntityGraph using @JsonIgnoreProperties("coupons") at Company class. Now I don't receive Company coupons when I GET companies. I hope this solution won't affect performance